# How to set an NFS network?

Tags: networking, network-manager, nfs, ufw, autofs

I want to merge information found here and there in order to record in one answer all steps to **set my NFS network between my two Ubuntu PCs**

This is useful time to time, for example when switching to a new Ubuntu version, I need to reset :

- [NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)
- [Autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs)
- [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets say that «boris» is my logon such as `/home/boris` is my home folder.

### 1. set the «server» computer:

- install [nfs-kernel-server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) and **nfs-common**

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
  $ sudo apt-get install nfs-common
  ```
- in `/etc/exports`, define the folder to be shared by adding this:

  ```
  /home/boris   192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,all_squash,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001,subtree_check)
  ```

  with:
  `/home/boris` is the folder to be shared
  `rw` for read and write access of the client
  `sync` ??
  `all_squash` ??
  `192.168.1.0/24` is a range of **client** computer IP address of your local network 
  `1001` is the user and group ID. To find it `$ id boris`
- manage hosts, 1st allow nobody in `/etc/hosts.deny` add

  ```
  portmap:ALL
  nfsd:ALL
  mountd:ALL
  ```

  Then allow your  **client** computer in `/etc/hosts.allow` add

  ```
  portmap:192.168.1.0/24
  lockd:192.168.1.0/24
  nfsd:192.168.1.0/24
  mountd:192.168.1.0/24
  rquotad:192.168.1.0/24
  statd:192.168.1.0/24
  ```

  with `192.168.1.0/24` is a range of **client** computer IP address of your local network
- set the firewall UFW

  ```
  $ sudo ufw enable
  $ sudo ufw default deny incoming
  $ sudo ufw default deny outgoing
  $ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24
  $ sudo ufw allow out from 192.168.1.0/24
  ```

  with `192.168.1.0/24` is a range of **client** computer IP address of your local network
- start the server

  ```
  $ sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start
  ```

  or after a modification of /etc/exports

  ```
  $ sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
  ```

### 2. set the «client» computer:

- install **nfs-common** and [autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs)

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install nfs-common
  $ sudo apt-get install autofs
  ```
- create the folder used to mount the connection with the server

  ```
  $ sudo mkdir /media/shareFolder
  ```
- set autofs to automatically mount this folder, 
  in `/etc/auto.master` add this line:

  ```
  /media/shareFolder /etc/auto.nfs --ghost, --timeout=60
  ```

  in `/etc/auto.nfs`  add this line

  ```
  boris  -fstype=nfs,rw,intr,uid=1001,guid=1001   192.168.1.1:/home/boris
  ```

  with:
  `192.168.1.1` is the address of **server** computer 
  `/home/boris` is the folder shared on **server** computer.
  `1001` is the user and group ID. To find it `$ id boris`
  `rw` for read and write access
- set the firewall UFW

  ```
  $ sudo ufw enable
  $ sudo ufw default deny incoming
  $ sudo ufw default deny outgoing
  $ sudo ufw allow to 192.168.1.1
  $ sudo ufw allow out to 192.168.1.1
  ```

  with `192.168.1.1` is the address of the **server** computer
- and reboot your **client** computer.

Comment: Very nice Boris.