# How to mount remote pen drive on my system using terminal

Tags: mount

I have computer A and computer B. I have attached a pendrive `/dev/sda5` on computer B and I want to mount it on computer A through terminal.

I don't want to use the GUI to connet to the server and then mount it. I want to mount through terminal. like: `mount root@X.X.X.X:/dev/sda5 /home/xyz/Desktop`
or something like this.

Comment: I do not know if there is such quick way to do that. An alternative could be to [set a NFS network between your 2 PCs](http://askubuntu.com/q/127675/32413)

Answer (score 0):

1) connect to computer B from computer via `ssh root@X.X.X.X:`

2) search for the dev entry point into the computer B system as following :

2.1) `lsusb` or `dmesg | grep -s "SCSI device"` or `grep  SCSI /var/log/messages`

with this, you will find the device entry point which will be used to mount the device.

3) create a mount point `mkdir -p /mnt/myusb`

4) `mount -t vfat -o rw,users /dev/sda1 /mnt/myusb`

(here, -t vfat is used to tell system that to mount vfat filesystem, with read/write permissions, and /dev/sda1 is the device entry point and /mnt/myusb is the directory where you will find the mounted device.)

Answer (score 0):

If your pendrive has UUID, you can do this:

```
ssh user@ip sudo sh -c "mkdir /media/usb && mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb"
```

Now if you want to access the contents of the pendrive in B from A you should set a [Network File Share which Boris](https://askubuntu.com/q/127675/32413) already gave a link.